# How to analyse a data set with more than 500 variables

Tags: multivariate-analysis, large-data, exploratory-data-analysis

I have a data set with 1000 entities. For each entity, more than 500 dichotomous variables (0,1) are recorded. I have no idea how to analyse this data or how to get an overview.
My problem is not that any analysis I attempt takes too long to run on the system, but that the result is equally confusing.
My question is whether there are statistical methods to aggregate this data. Or to get an overview, e.g. of the correlation between variables.
Or in general, if there are special statistical methods to handle data sets with such a lot of variables in a way that the result is a bit more compact.
I don't even know how to start and would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Are these binary variables the result of one-hot-encoding?

Comment: Why is 500 variables too much? `import numpy as np; from sklearn.decomposition import PCA; X = np.random.normal(size=1000*500).reshape(1000,500); PCA(n_components=2).fit_transform(X)` runs in less than a second on my system. The optimal suitability of PCA due to the binary variables is a valid concern, but is distinct concern from the size of the data.

Comment: I also find that `import numpy as np; from sklearn.decomposition import PCA; X = np.random.randint(0,2,size=1000*500).reshape(1000,500); PCA(n_components=2).fit_transform(X)` completes pretty much instantly.

Comment: What is the goal of this analysis? There are different methods for different purposes.

Comment: To add to @Galen's questions: You should also describe the data. What are the entities? how was the data collected? what are these 500 binary features? can you group the features into groups of features that describe different aspects of the entities? what do you mean by "overview"? ...

Comment: We understand that it is difficult to know where to start!!!  But, for us to help, you need to tell us about your data and research questio0n in plain language! What does your variables represent in the real world?  Sample size? ... See  https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1479/how-to-ask-a-good-question-on-crossvalidated

Answer (score 4):

Asking "how do I analyze this dataset" without reference to a research question is like asking "what do I do with this pile of wood." Well, you could turn it into a house, or a desk, or a chair, or an abstract sculpture. It depends on what you need, and there is no way for anyone to give you advice on what to do unless you tell them what you are trying to do.. That being said, once you have decided you want to build a chair, then there are some clear guidelines and best practices to help you build a GOOD chair (and avoid making a bad one).

Similarly, Data analysis is a process of using various mathematical tools (analogous to hammers and screwdrivers) to answer questions using data (the "raw material"). It doesn't matter if your dataset has 2 variables or 500 or a million, you can't coherently talk about "analyzing" it except in reference to a specific question or set of questions. Once you have a question then you can think about which variables in the dataset, and what analytic tools, could help you to answer that question.

So for example, a really common kind of question in data analysis involves trying to figure out whether a specific "dependent variable" is in some way associated with (or caused by?) one or more independent variables, after accounting for other confounding variables. This sort of question is often analyzed using tools like regression analysis, but setting up the model depends on what particular dependent and independent variables you are interested in. Does participating in the program make people more likely to get a job? Do Black patients get the same care as White patients? Are different kinds of diets effective at loosing weight?

Another type of question you might ask is whether a bunch of different questions all measure one or more underlying latent constructs. Do these 10 questions about "depression" all tap some underlying construct of "depression" and if so is there a way to aggregate this data together to create a single measure of "depression?" This kind of question of often answered with tools like factor analysis or principle components analysis.

But again, none of this has any meaning in the abstract. Data analysis is about asking and answering questions. Without a question, the data is just a pile of wood.

Answer (score 0):

#### Pre-Analysis

I have had to do this for a lab in the past, so I can probably provide some guidance. First off, your very first resource for such an extensive dataset is the group of people who came up with it in the first place. If you can contact the people who made it, they can provide a lot of background information on what variables are important, what they mean, how they were devised, etc. They may even have a handbook or manual that outlines every variable, which would be extremely helpful. If that information is not accessible, you can also see if the dataset has been cited in articles already, and from there you can also derive some insights.

#### Finding What's Useful

For the actual data side of things, once you have established which variables are important, I recommend condensing or splitting the data into meaningful parts. For example, if you have 50 variables for Variable X and Variable Z, but you also have 450 nonsense variables that are dichotomous, you can use a code like this:

```
#### Load Data Wrangling Package ####
library(tidyverse)

#### Split Data Meaningfully ####
data.split <- data %>% 
  select(contains("Variable_X"),
         contains("Variable_Y"))
```

Perhaps all of these dichotomous variables are in wide format (it sounds like it from what you explained) and you need to convert them to long format (for an explanation of what this means, there is [a good article on this by Hadley Wickham](https://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.pdf). One example is R's `relig_income` dataset, which has many income brackets:

```
relig_income %>% 
  head()
```

Which is messy:

```
# A tibble: 6 × 11
  religion  `<$10k` $10-2…¹ $20-3…² $30-4…³ $40-5…⁴ $50-7…⁵ $75-1…⁶
  <chr>       <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1 Agnostic       27      34      60      81      76     137     122
2 Atheist        12      27      37      52      35      70      73
3 Buddhist       27      21      30      34      33      58      62
4 Catholic      418     617     732     670     638    1116     949
5 Don’t kn…      15      14      15      11      10      35      21
6 Evangeli…     575     869    1064     982     881    1486     949
# … with 3 more variables: `$100-150k` <dbl>, `>150k` <dbl>,
#   `Don't know/refused` <dbl>, and abbreviated variable names
#   ¹​`$10-20k`, ²​`$20-30k`, ³​`$30-40k`, ⁴​`$40-50k`, ⁵​`$50-75k`,
#   ⁶​`$75-100k`
```

But is easier read in long format:

```
relig_income %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = 2:11,
               names_to = "Income_Bracket",
               values_to = "Amount") %>% 
  head()
```

And now looks easier to read:

```
  religion Income_Bracket Amount
  <chr>    <chr>           <dbl>
1 Agnostic <$10k              27
2 Agnostic $10-20k            34
3 Agnostic $20-30k            60
4 Agnostic $30-40k            81
5 Agnostic $40-50k            76
6 Agnostic $50-75k           137
```

#### Visualization

There are also some visualization codes you can use to look at the data that you think is worth running. For example, the `skimr` package has a good quick look at how your data is distributed:

```
library(skimr)
skim(relig_income)

Which gives you this:

── Data Summary ────────────────────────
                           Values      
Name                       relig_income
Number of rows             18          
Number of columns          11          
_______________________                
Column type frequency:                 
  character                1           
  numeric                  10          
________________________               
Group variables            None        

── Variable type: character ───────────────────────────────────────
  skim_variable n_missing complete_rate min max empty n_unique
1 religion              0             1   5  23     0       18
  whitespace
1          0

── Variable type: numeric ─────────────────────────────────────────
   skim_variable      n_missing complete_rate mean   sd p0  p25
 1 <$10k                      0             1 107. 169.  1 12.2
 2 $10-20k                    0             1 154. 255.  2 14.8
 3 $20-30k                    0             1 186. 310.  3 17  
 4 $30-40k                    0             1 183. 291.  4 15.8
 5 $40-50k                    0             1 171. 271.  2 15  
 6 $50-75k                    0             1 288. 458.  7 34.2
 7 $75-100k                   0             1 222. 345.  3 25.2
 8 $100-150k                  0             1 178. 276.  4 22.5
 9 >150k                      0             1 145. 205.  4 23.8
10 Don't know/refused         0             1 340. 531.  8 41.2
    p50  p75 p100 hist 
 1 20   170   575 ▇▁▁▁▁
 2 27   193   869 ▇▁▁▁▁
 3 33.5 192  1064 ▇▁▁▁▁
 4 40   199.  982 ▇▁▁▁▁
 5 34   167.  881 ▇▁▁▁▁
 6 66.5 202. 1486 ▇▁▁▁▁
 7 65.5 129.  949 ▇▁▁▁▂
 8 48.5 104.  792 ▇▁▁▁▂
 9 53.5 134.  634 ▇▁▁▁▁
10 74.5 295. 1529 ▇▁▁▁▂
```

Maybe you are only interested in the numeric data and you have a ton of uninteresting categorical variables. Using the `starwars` dataset, we can see that there are a lot of non-numeric values that we may not be interested in.

```
glimpse(starwars)
```

Which you can see:

```
Rows: 87
Columns: 14
$ name       <chr> "Luke Skywalker", "C-3PO", "R2-D2", "Darth Vade…
$ height     <int> 172, 167, 96, 202, 150, 178, 165, 97, 183, 182,…
$ mass       <dbl> 77.0, 75.0, 32.0, 136.0, 49.0, 120.0, 75.0, 32.…
$ hair_color <chr> "blond", NA, NA, "none", "brown", "brown, grey"…
$ skin_color <chr> "fair", "gold", "white, blue", "white", "light"…
$ eye_color  <chr> "blue", "yellow", "red", "yellow", "brown", "bl…
$ birth_year <dbl> 19.0, 112.0, 33.0, 41.9, 19.0, 52.0, 47.0, NA, …
$ sex        <chr> "male", "none", "none", "male", "female", "male…
$ gender     <chr> "masculine", "masculine", "masculine", "masculi…
$ homeworld  <chr> "Tatooine", "Tatooine", "Naboo", "Tatooine", "A…
$ species    <chr> "Human", "Droid", "Droid", "Human", "Human", "H…
$ films      <list> <"The Empire Strikes Back", "Revenge of the Si…
$ vehicles   <list> <"Snowspeeder", "Imperial Speeder Bike">, <>, …
$ starships  <list> <"X-wing", "Imperial shuttle">, <>, <>, "TIE A…
```

You can gather the data that's useful to you and visualize their distributions that way:

```
starwars %>% 
  keep(is.numeric) %>% 
  gather() %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=value))+
  geom_density(fill="green",
               alpha= .4)+
  facet_wrap(~key,
             scales = "free")+
  labs(title = "Star Wars Numeric Data",
       x="Value",
       y="Density")
```

[image]

There are probably a lot of other ways you can look at data. Something that may help is reading the book *R for Data Science*. I think it does a good job of explaining how to wrangle data, even if learning it for the first time can be frustratingly difficult as a beginner. Also, [this guide](https://towardsdatascience.com/an-extensive-guide-to-exploratory-data-analysis-ddd99a03199e) may be helpful if you want something shorter. Though it is more focused on Python, the actual process of exploring and cleaning data is well explained there. Hope that is helpful and let me know if you have questions.

#### Analysis

As for the analysis part...it doesn't appear clear what you are actually trying to do with the data yet. This is common with people who first analyze large datasets, but the problem is largely alleviated when you know which direction to walk. I would first figure out what questions you are trying to answer with your data...are you trying to look at differences in height between genders? Are you looking to employ some form of machine learning to estimate what predicts hiring and firing in a corporation? It helps to have a solid preliminary reason for why you are even looking at the numbers in front of you. Additionally, if you have questions about a specific stats method, its better to ask about that rather than analysis in general, as that can be a years-long topic given the vast depth of statistical topics out there.